# why the restriction of a normal operator is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra

can anyone explain why it's obvious that a normal operator restricted to a invariant subspace is still normal?

[image]

Comment: Define the restricted operator $M = TP$ where $P$ is the projection into the invariant subspace. Can you show that $M^*M = MM^*$?

Comment: @cameron wlilliams  sorry i cant. if the subspace is also T* invariant, i think the conclusion is obvious. but that's a corollary of what Artin prepare to prove.

Comment: Just use prop. 8.6.3 (b). If T is normal the equality holds for all vectors in your space, does it also hold for all vectors in your invariant subspace?

Comment: @Dasi also has a good way to prove it. It's also the slightly easier way to do it.

Comment: @Dasi but T* is the conjugate of the restricted operator, not the restrict of the conjugate.  am i misunderstanding? in this sense i see hermitian and unitary are obviously preserved

Comment: @ysTuan True, but it is easy to see that those are the same thing (you just have to test that the restriction of the conjugate fits the definition of the conjugate of the restriction. It's basically the same argument as above: If the equality holds for the whole space it also holds for any subspace)

Comment: @Dasi  i cant even see why the subspace is invariant under the restriction of conjugate, so how it act on the subspace directly

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_0:=T_{|W}$. Now prove:

$$(T^*)_{|W}=T_0^*.$$

Comment: But why is $W$ invariant under $T^*$?

Answer (score 0):

Other way to see it as follows:
Suppose $T$ is normal and
$$TT^*(v)=T^*T(v)$$, this is true for all $v \in V$,
Now,
Claim: $T_{|W}:W \rightarrow W$ is normal. So,
$$\langle T^*Tw,w' \rangle=\langle TT^*w,w' \rangle $$
for all $w,w' \in W$.
So,
$$T^*Tw=TT^*w$$ for all $w \in W$.
Hence $T_{|W}$ is normal.

Comment: This answer is flawed. The argument is circular.

Answer (score 0):

> Lemma : $T$ is normal iff $T^*=p(T)$ where $p(T)$ is a polynomial of T.

> proof: if  $T^*=p(T)$, then $T$, $T^*$ commutes so $T$ is normal.
>
> Conversely, if $T$ is normal, we can decompose $T$ such that $T=\sum \lambda_i T_i$ and $T^*=\sum \bar{\lambda_i} T_i$. $p(T)=T=\sum p(\lambda_i) T_i$. By interpolating the polynomial $p$, we can find such $p$.

So by the lemma, if $W$ is $T$ invariant, it should also be $T^*$ invariant.

we can then get $(T_W)^*=T^*_W$.

Thus, $T_W(T_W)^*=(T_W)^*T_W$.